# Programmatically Crop image after resize

Tags: image

How i can first resize then crop image. I already use `Varien_Image` like this :

```
        $imageObj = new Varien_Image($_imageUrl);
        $imageObj->constrainOnly(false);
        $imageObj->keepAspectRatio(false);
        $imageObj->keepFrame(false);
        $imageObj->crop($cutH, $cut, $cut,$cutH);
        $imageObj->resize(floor($width), floor($height));
        $imageObj->save($_imageUrl);
        return $imageUrl;
```

th code above first crop then resize. but i want first resize then crop and also i want only resize width not height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the sequence of calling method `crop` and `resize` as below

```
$imageObj = new Varien_Image($_imageUrl);
        $imageObj->constrainOnly(false);
        $imageObj->keepAspectRatio(false);
        $imageObj->keepFrame(false);
        $imageObj->resize(floor($width), floor($height));
        $imageObj->crop($cutH, $cut, $cut,$cutH);
        $imageObj->save($_imageUrl);
        return $imageUrl;
```

Comment: I did it before, this will show error of not correct size

Comment: Try crop with hardcoded values like crop(10, 20, 30, 40) and check if you are still getting the same error.